# Flutter Plugin - Example App - Only runs via Xcode, not by itself

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm creating a flutter plugin and I just tried the example project that gets created by flutter it self. This example project is an app that shows the operation system and its version. If I start it from Xcode on my iPhone SE, it works fine.
But if I close the app and open it without Xcode, that means that I tipp on the app icon to launche it, like every normal app, it doesn't start correctly.
It is showing for not even a second a white screen, followed by a black screen and is closing the app right after this.

1. Why is it behaving like that?
2. Is it, because it is a debug version and needs Xcode?
3. How can I put my example app on my iPhone without needing a connection to Xcode to start it?

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: Thanks to the answer of Răzvan Puiu below, i know now that this is because xCode puts the app as a debug version on my iPhone. This debug version can only run with xCode. After I tried it with a 'normal' app and not the example app of a plugin project, i even got this text shown if i tried to start the debug version without xCode:
[image]

So the solution is to run the app with:

> flutter run --release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I believe it behaves like that because you don't have an Apple developer account. "Without enrolling in the Apple Developer Program, your app will only last for 7 days on your device. After that, you’ll have to re-deploy it to your device via Xcode. If you’re enrolled in the Apple Developer Program, you won’t have this inconvenience."
2. Yes
3. You can run `flutter run --release` and then select your physical device. However the app will remain on your phone for only 7 days unless you have the Apple dev account.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. I just tried it with a 'normal' flutter app and not the example app of a plugin project. If i try to start the debug version of this 'normal' app without xCode, it even shows a text, that debug can only run with xCode.
Because I can't poste an image here in this commend i will edit my question and add a screenshot of this text.